# Prove every finite extension of subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ is simple

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

This is a question is from a past paper, and it's only worth 8 marks, and it's really got me. I'm allowed to assume that if $L/K$ is such an extension, that there are $[L:K]$ $K$-embeddings of $L$ into $\mathbb{C}$.

I was thinking the only way to do this would be to show some $\alpha$ such that $L=K(\alpha)$ exists, though I have no ideas about how to. The hint doesn't seem to help me much; the $K$-embeddings of a simple extension are completely determined by what they do to the adjoined element, but how could I use this? Knowing how many embeddings there are doesn't seem to help show that such an element exists.

Answer (score 1):

By the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem), finite separable extensions are simple. This doesn't use the hint, though.